# Basic math issue

Tags: math, calculator

I'm trying to create a calculator that helps you know what is the return on each investment. I know this is a funny question but i got stuck in a very simple math problem.

Lets say someone invested 20dollars and the price for an apple was 5,000dollars.

1 month later, the price went up to 14,500dollars. A rise of 290%.

How much will that 20dollar be worth? is it 20dollars + 290% , or 20dollars * 290%? or is it 20dollars * 290. Sorry for asking a silly question but im blanked out.

Comment: How does the price of an apple effect the value of an investment? Your question doesn't really explain what you have in mind. In any event, it isn't really a programming question so is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a math question which isn't about programming

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about mathematics / economics / accounting and not programming or coding.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down simple.

Let's say you invested 10 dollars for the price of 1000.

and the value hiked to 2000.

So your 10 dollars will be worth 20 now. aka 10 * 200%.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Always here to help :))